# Problem with chrome: cascading tab list not displayed, have to do it blindly

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chrome-for-android, troubleshooting, application-error

Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini
Android 6.0.1
Chrome 86.0.4240.198 (latest update at the moment)

Just yesterday Chrome's tabbing started misbehaving.

When pressing the button to look at the list of tabs, the display with a cascade of tabs doesn't show/refresh. Sometimes even the webpage shown before doesn't seem to disappear and the only indicator that you should be seeing tabs is the + over the homepage button. Occasionally the tabs will show but won't appear to scroll (though they do).

It appears to work as it should, but without displaying. Think putting a blindfold on when manipulating tabs. You can scroll through tabs, close tabs by swiping, switch to another tab, as if it had displayed them. When you do switch to any (random) tab, you take a blindfold off / the page and surroundings displays normally, no trace of any fault. Here's an example with 2 tabs:

[image: SE site]
[image: Tabs]
[image: Weather page]
[image: Tabs]

Explanation: I see the **1st screenshot**: 2nd tab, the main StackExchange page. I tap the "tabs" button on the right of the address bar. Then I see the **2nd screenshot**: cascading tabs not displayed properly. I drag downwards but the display stays the same, as if frozen. Proof that *it did scroll*: the upper part of the screen should be displaying the first tab; I tap where the orange "Learn more" button appears to be and I open the 1st tab, BBC Weather page, as seen on the **3rd screenshot**. I open tabs again, see the **4th screenshot**: cascading tabs. I drag up and again, like frozen. But *it did scroll invisibly again*, because I tap at the bottom (Sunrise, Sunset) and end up seeing the **1st screenshot**: 2nd tab.

I have restarted the phone a few times and uninstalled+reinstalled Chrome (uninstalled updates, reverting to the built-in version, which also wiped out the app's data), but to no avail. I haven't found anything on the internet about these symptoms either.

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Done, I've edited the question.